# How to chain ObservableObject?

Tags: asynchronous, swiftui, combine

I have a Game-object that may hold an image. Whenever an image URL is found for a game a new instance of GameImage-object should be created. It will then fetch the image and populate the UIImage property. When this happens the UI should be updated presenting the image.

```
class Game: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: GameImage?
} 

class GameImage: ObservableObject {
    let url: URL
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }
    
    func fetch() {
        self.cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: self.url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] (image) in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.image = image
                print(self.url)
                print(self.image)
            })
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var game = Game()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let image = game.image?.image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
            } else {
                Text("No image.")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            guard let gameImageURL = URL(string: "https://cf.geekdo-images.com/itemrep/img/oVEpcbtyWkJjIjk1peTJo6hI1yk=/fit-in/246x300/pic4884996.jpg") else { return }
            game.image = GameImage(url: gameImageURL)
            game.image!.fetch()
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is. After fetch is done the debug console will show that image contains an UIImage. However the UI does not update to show the image. What am I missing here?

Comment: Would you show the UI dependent on this view model?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The Game-instance `game` should contain the single source of truth. The Game-object can also contain other properties like name which I removed from this sample to not over complicate things. Whenever an image comes available it should present it, in that way it is dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much more simpler solution than chaining `ObservableObject`, just separate dependent part into standalone subview... and all will work automatically.

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var game = Game()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if nil != game.image {
                GameImageView(vm: game.image!)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            guard let gameImageURL = URL(string: "https://cf.geekdo-images.com/itemrep/img/oVEpcbtyWkJjIjk1peTJo6hI1yk=/fit-in/246x300/pic4884996.jpg") else { return }
            game.image = GameImage(url: gameImageURL)
            game.image!.fetch()
        })
    }
}

struct GameImageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: GameImage

    var body: some View {
        if let image = vm.image {
            Image(uiImage: image)
        } else {
            Text("No image.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better not to force-unwrap optionals? Can't it be `game.image?.fetch()`? I know this was in the question but you can always improve it.

Comment: Yes, although in this example I set the game.image one line above so it's pretty safe.

Comment: I just tested the code and it worked. I am still trying to wrap my head around the concept.

Comment: @Mark Sure, but as a good practice I recommend to not to force-unwrap optionals. You may copy this line somewhere else later and then forget about it.